# Can't using ReferenceInput in admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

Here is the ref : [Admin-on-Rest](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#referenceinput)

in app.js :

```
<Resource name="customers" list={CustomerList} icon={UserIcon} edit={CustomerEdit} create={CustomerCreate}/>
```

in customer.js :

```
  <TextInput source="firstname" />
  <ReferenceInput label="Partner" source="id" reference="partners" >
      <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
  </ReferenceInput>
  <TextInput source="email" />
```

The problem is autocomplete not shown, but I check in log data retrieved from API end point /partners

And if I change reference to reference="customers", data and autocomplete shown.

Help please ??

Answer (score 3):

You need another `<Resource>` for the relationship, even empty:

```
<Resource name="customers" list={CustomerList} icon={UserIcon} edit={CustomerEdit} create={CustomerCreate}/>
<Resource name="partners" />
```

It is well documented for [`<ReferenceField>`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencefield) (see the note), perhaps it needs the same note for `<ReferenceInput>`.

Comment: Hi @francois, Where I should put <Resource name="partners" /> ? is it on App.js or customers.js ? I already set componen <Resource name="partners" list={PartnerList} icon={UserIcon} edit={PartnerEdit} create={PartnerCreate}/> on App.js

Comment: All `<Resource>` components must be direct children of the `<Admin>` component.

Answer (score 0):

You `<ReferenceInput reference="...">` needs to match the `<Resource name="...">` for this to work. So this is the reason why `reference="customers"` worked for you.

If you want to get data from `customers` endpoints, but you want the `label` to be `Partner` you can specify it as `label` attribute on your `ReferenceInput` component, e.g. `<ReferenceInput label="Partner" ...>`.

Comment: So the question is : is it possible to change ?  the point is I need to get partner data.

Comment: If you have an endpoint `customers`, you  change the reference to `customers`. However, the label you display is up to you, so you can display `Partners`. Or do you want to access `partners` API endpoint?

Comment: Yes I need get partners data on customers module.

Comment: @Khalid I have updated my answer. Does specifying the `label` work for you?

Comment: not work. what I know label only static word which's only displayed above of the input (Partners).

Comment: Yes, I need get partners data in customers module <Resource name="customers" list={CustomerList} icon={UserIcon} edit={CustomerEdit} create={CustomerCreate}/>

Comment: @Khalid Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137024/discussion-between-deividas-karzinauskas-and-khalid).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the way you're importing your 'ReferenceInput' object. I had the same issue while creating my app and had no idea what is the problem. 
Check your import line and if it looks like this:

```
import {ReferenceInput} from "../../src/mui/input/ReferenceInput";
```

then change it to look this way:

```
import ReferenceInput from '../../src/mui/input/ReferenceInput';
```

Hope that helps you!